# reusing stateful react components

Tags: reactjs, components

I'm new to React and wanted some advice.

The problem is essentially thew following

I have a number of component buttons that open a modal, within this modal we have further buttons to offer a selection.

Home Screen Buttons (components)

```
<Button value="First"></button>
<Button value="Second"></button>
<Button value="Third"></button>.....
```

Modal.

```
<button value="Donald"></button>
<button value="Thomas"></button>
<button value="Evie"></button>.....
```

So the home screen buttons for example would have the following function, that it would pass down to the modal buttons onClick attribute.

```
selectPerson(e) {
  setState({ selection : e.target.value})
}
```

So by selecting "First", we choose a person, close the modal, tie the selected person with Buttons state, and then repeat for second and so on.

Essentially these Buttons to open the modal have the same core functions (state and props). i.e I could have a template component an reuse it, but I would like each component to have independent state and props.

So I can achieve what I need but I've written each home screen button as an independent component, that is I've written a lot of the same code. If I attempt to reuse the SAME component, the  are treated as the same component, and selecting a person changes all buttons state.

Is there anyway to avoid rewriting the same code for each  (I have twenty). I've only just started (obviously) and am not too familiar with some of the more advanced concepts. If anyone has any suggestions or further questions, it would be great. I haven't provided code as the code works, its just extremely bulky

Comment: Can you provide a specific example with code of how reusing a component reuses its state as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah sure, define the button components and hand down certain elements inside its props. 
You can then setState to be these handed down prop elements etc etc.

So define a button component with its various states defined by the props you hand it down. Then you have a mutable template Button component.

When you render these you just define its props.

```
<Button prop = "First" prop2 = "EXAMPLE"..../>
<Button prop = "Second" prop2 = "EXAMPLE2"..../>
<Button prop = "Third" prop2 = "EXAMPLE3"..../>
```

then inside the Button component use something like

```
this.state { property1 : this.props.prop, property2 : this.props.prop2 ...}
```

Hope this helps! I've recently been doing something similar